# YouCompleteMe can't import libtinfo.so.5

Tags: linux, vim

I tried to install the vim plugin `YouCompleteMe`. When I now start vim I get the error

```
The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with ':YcmRestartServer'). Unexpected error while loading the YCM core library. Type ':YcmToggleLogs ycmd_55497_stderr_9xkqrg__.log' to check the logs.
```

In the error log it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alex/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/server_utils.py", line 96, in CompatibleWithCurrentCore
    ycm_core = ImportCore()
  File "/home/alex/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/ycmd/server_utils.py", line 88, in ImportCore
    import ycm_core as ycm_core
ImportError: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I then looked for `libtinfo` in my `/usr/lib` directory and apparently I only have `libtinfo.so.6.1` and `libtinfo.so.6` (6 seems to just be a symbolic link to 6.1).

When I search for `libtinfo` in dnf I get no result at all (not even version 6 or 6.1) so I think it might be part of a different package and that is why I don't get a result. Is there a way to find out which package I need to install to get version 5 or is there a better way to fix this?

(Fedora 28, vim 8.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing `ncurses-compat-libs.x86_64` solved the problem.